# Jolt conversion to convert json as page url parameter

Tags: json, jolt

I need help in jolt transformation to create URL queries from `keys` and `values` in the object.

**Input:**

```json
{
  "a": 10,
  "b": 20,
  "c": "Name"
}
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "requests": ["?a=10&b=20&c=Name"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "keys",
        "@": "values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "keys": {
        "0": {
          "#?": "requests",
          "@": "requests",
          "#=": "requests",
          "@(3,values[&])": "requests"
        },
        "*": {
          "#\\&": "requests",
          "@": "requests",
          "#=": "requests",
          "@(3,values[&])": "requests"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@0)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: it's great @Mohammad !

Comment: @Mohammad Excellent. Thanks for the help. Can you tell me what change do i i need to do if i need output as {
  "requests" : ["?a=10&b=20&c=Name"]
}. I have updated the output in question as well

Comment: Hi @Datadev , you just can add one more spec : `{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&[]"
    }
  }`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks a lot, my role model.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Please add your spec to my answer.

Comment: @Datadev new spec added by Barbaros Özhan is ok. you can add it to your spec.

Comment: I mean to add your spec which is your idea to my answer.